# What does $\cos(n,t)$ mean?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, notation

In the book by JL Lions "Quelques methodes...", (Chapter 2, Section 3.3, page 197), he uses the notation
$$\cos(n,t)$$
in a boundary condition on a domain $\Omega(t)$, where $n$ denotes the normal vector. What does this mean?? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: May it be the cosinus of the angle between the vectors $n$ and $t$?

Comment: @DanielMuñozParsapoormoghadam I think not, because $t$ stands for time and is not a vector

Comment: Where explicitly did he use it? Could you provide the chapter-no, page-no, etc.. maybe you could also quote a full paragraph where he use this notation?

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 See the edit. I guess it is something to do with the normal derivative.

Comment: Maybe you can deduce it from p.89 between (6.132) and (6.133).